# keyup event handler changes focus not working for quick typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I want a PIN entry form where each character is typed into a separate html input.

I am trying to capture keyup events in javascript so that I can change focus to the next input element, saving the user from needing to change it themselves with a mouse click or a tab.

It is working unless the user types really quickly. For example, if the user types the characters '1' and '2' really quickly, I find the first input now correctly has the character '1', while the second input is still empty, and the focus has moved on to the third input.

Why?

Here's the code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.pinchar').keyup(function (e) {
    
                if (
                    (e.which == 8) //backspace
                    || (e.which == 46) // del
                    || (e.which == 9) // tab
                    || (e.which == 13) // return
                    || (e.which == 27) // esc
                    || (e.which == 37) // arrow
                    || (e.which == 38) // arrow
                    || (e.which == 39) // arrow
                    || (e.which == 40) // arrow
                    || (e.which == 27) // esc
                    || (e.which == 20) // CAPS LOCK 
                    || (e.which == 17) // Ctrl
                    || (e.which == 18) // Alt 
                    || (e.which == 16)) { //shift

                    return false;
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().next().find('.pinchar').focus();
                }
            });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="enterPINTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN1" id="txtPIN1" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN2" id="txtPIN2" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN3" id="txtPIN3" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN4" id="txtPIN4" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: you don't have closing `});` this is weird but for me works

Comment: Thanks, Grisza, Sorry..closing }); was missing ... But only a typo above.  I don't see where iteration would be or how it might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`keyup` will fail when you press a key, and then before releasing it, press another. The order of events is then `keydown 1`, `keydown 2`, `keyup 1`, `keydown 2`. But as characters are produced following `keydown`  (and `keypress`) you'll already have two characters in the `input` before the first `keyup` event in that case.

Instead try the `input` event:

```
  $('.pinchar').on('input', function (e) {
       // ... etc.
```

It is triggered immediately on any change.

But to treat other keys correctly, you need to trap the `keydown` event as well (for arrow and backspace keys).

I would suggest this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $inputs = $(".enterPINTable .pinchar");
    function step(inp, dir, clr) {
        if (clr) $(inp).val("");
        var buffer = $(inp).val(); // get excess characters
        // spread characters in next boxes to ensure max 1 char
        var curr = $inputs.index(inp);
        for (var i = curr, j = 0; j < buffer.length && i < $inputs.length; i++, j++) { 
             $inputs.eq(i).val(buffer[j]);
        }
        if (dir < 0) curr-= curr > 0;
        else curr = Math.min(curr + (j||dir), $inputs.length-1);
        var $next = $inputs.eq(curr);
        $next.focus();
        setTimeout(function () { 
            $next.select();
        }, 0);
        return false;
    }
    $inputs.on("focus", function () {
        $(this).select(); // always select the "whole" (1 char) text
    }).on("mouseup", function () { // Attempt to unselect?
        setTimeout(function () { // Keep character selected....
            $(this).select();
        }.bind(this));
    }).on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.key == "ArrowLeft" || e.key == "ArrowUp") return step(this, -1);
        if (e.key == "ArrowRight" || e.key == "ArrowDown") return step(this, 1);
        if (e.key == "Backspace") return step(this, -1, 1);
    }).on("input", function (e) {
        step(this, 0);
    }).eq(0).focus();
});
```

```css
.pinchar { width: 1em; text-align: center }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="enterPINTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="txtPIN1" id="txtPIN1" class="pinchar">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="txtPIN2" id="txtPIN2" class="pinchar">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="txtPIN3" id="txtPIN3" class="pinchar">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="txtPIN4" id="txtPIN4" class="pinchar">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above code aims to always select the current character, so that if you type another character it replaces the current one. If you would succeed to remove the selection (not easy) and try to add a second character, it will end up in the next box. Pasting of a series of characters from the clipboard will also result in a spread of one character per input box.

`left`, `right`, `tab`, `shift`+`tab`, `backspace`, and `delete` keys work as could be expected.

Using CSS to size the inputs, and centering the text, seems to give a better result.

Comment: Excellent. Works well and I like the handling of arrows abd backspaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Keypress is better suited in this case.**

The problem is that keyup is triggered late , i.e. after keydown and keypress.
*This is how the order goes:* 

When key is pressed,  then instantly keydown event is triggered. At that event the value is not printed on the screen. After that keypress is triggered, at this time the value is printed. 
After both the events, keyup is triggered, when you lift the fingers off the key. 

So when you press two keys quickly,their keypress is called in quick succession(it is when value is printed on screen), so value is printed on the same input,  then keyup for both is called which forwards focus to next of next input (leaving them empty because value has already been printed during keypress).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.pinchar').keypress(function (e) {
    
               $(this).parent().next().find('.pinchar').focus();
               
            });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="enterPINTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN1" id="txtPIN1" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN2" id="txtPIN2" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN3" id="txtPIN3" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="txtPIN4" id="txtPIN4" class="pinchar" size="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: keypress is deprecated and not works in all browsers if we consider cross-browser support if not consider so ok

Comment: This also works. Perhaps Grisza has a point about keypress being deprecated, but notwithstanding, this still solution also works.