# JS/jQuery - Credit Card Expiry with auto slash issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I am having is that if you type quickly, it doesn't convert this correctly to MM/YY, something like the following could happen:

[image]

Secondly, pasting in the value I would expect to auto convert as well. I tried adding paste to no avail.

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7twp43rx/).

```js
$('.card-expiry').on('keyup change blur', function(e) {
  formatCCExpiryDate(e);
});

function formatCCExpiryDate(e) {
  var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  var code = event.keyCode;
  var allowedKeys = [8];
  if (allowedKeys.indexOf(code) !== -1) {
    return;
  }

  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(
    /^([1-9]\/|[2-9])$/g, '0$1/'
  ).replace(
    /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/g, '$1/'
  ).replace(
    /^([0-1])([3-9])$/g, '0$1/$2'
  ).replace(
    /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-9]{2})$/g, '$1/$2'
  ).replace(
    /^([0]+)\/|[0]+$/g, '0'
  ).replace(
    /[^\d\/]|^[\/]*$/g, ''
  ).replace(
    /\/\//g, '/'
  );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Expiration</label>
<div class="inline-fields">
  <input class="card-expiry" placeholder="MM / YY" type="tel" maxlength="5" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp" autocompletetype="cc-exp" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="off" autocapitalize="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Why `type="tel"?`

Comment: @KooiInc So I didn't have to add `onkeydown="if(event.key==='.'){event.preventDefault();}"` if I was using `type="number"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use input or [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) event, instead of keyup event. [Keyup will fail when you press a key, and then before releasing it, press another. This may cause a problem as on fast typing there may be multiple keys which may not be released.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330782/5740382) For example, if you continuously press 1 you will end up with 11111 rather then 11/11. To handle the pasting option you can use input event in jQuery see the following example.

Note: [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event is not the part of [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) so, properties like [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key),  [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) are not available. To detect the backspace/delete key we need to use [InputEvent.inputType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType). For example,

```
event.inputType == "deleteContentBackward" // Backspace
event.inputType == "deleteContentForward"  // Delete
```

for full list of `inputType` see: https://rawgit.com/w3c/input-events/v1/index.html#interface-InputEvent-Attributes

```js
$('.card-expiry').on('input', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.inputType == "deleteContentBackward") {
    return;
  }
  formatCCExpiryDate($(this));
});

function formatCCExpiryDate($target) {
  var inputChar = $target.val();
  //var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  //console.log(inputChar);
  //var code = e.keyCode;
  var allowedKeys = [8];
  if (allowedKeys.indexOf(inputChar) !== -1) {
    return;
  }

  var maskedValue = inputChar.replace(
    /^([1-9]\/|[2-9])$/g, '0$1/'
  ).replace(
    /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/g, '$1/'
  ).replace(
    /^([0-1])([3-9])$/g, '0$1/$2'
  ).replace(
    /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-9]{2})$/g, '$1/$2'
  ).replace(
    /^([0]+)\/|[0]+$/g, '0'
  ).replace(
    /[^\d\/]|^[\/]*$/g, ''
  ).replace(
    /\/\//g, '/'
  );
  $target.val(maskedValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Expiration</label>
<div class="inline-fields">
  <input class="card-expiry" placeholder="MM / YY" type="tel" maxlength="5" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp" autocompletetype="cc-exp" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="off" autocapitalize="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The only issue with this is that I can no longer press the delete key to remove the month once you've gone to the year.

Comment: But If I've added e.g. 12/24, I can only remove 24 so it becomes 12/ - Before I could remove the entire value.

Comment: @nsilva you can detect backspace/delete key. code might look like `if (e.originalEvent.inputType == "deleteContentBackward") {
    return;
  }` I have update my code.

Comment: @nsilva for all the possible value of inputType https://rawgit.com/w3c/input-events/v1/index.html#interface-InputEvent-Attributes

Comment: Legend, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead of the *keyup* event. The input event will fire for each input change, including paste operations, ensuring the format is updated in real-time.

```
$('.card-expiry').on('input change blur', function(e) {
  formatCCExpiryDate(e);
});
```